# Diagrams to describe behavior of application

Tags: uml, diagram

I built an application which is integrated in open source program( you just download the binary of the program, run it and then my integrated module will execute when you click on one single button called translate. That's all. )

What the application does is that when user builds some schema in the open-source project I mentioned above it generates C++ code for the schema. It's java program written in OOP style( classes, polymorphism, inheritance, encapsulation). There also runs some algorithms like top sort for finding topological sorting or bfs.

Since I study software engineering and will be presenting the application I would like to draw some `UML` diagrams or diagrams in general which would help me to better describe the application/ behavior of application itself.

Since it's not typical web-based project ( does not use any database etc... ) except for `class diagram` I don't know what what would be good to use.

Could anyone give me some diagram names which would help me to describe the behavior of my application better? I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [sequence diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html), [activity diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) and/or [state diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html) to describe behavior.

Comment: I forgot to mention state diagrams which are also very handy in many cases.